# path.getTotalLength() returning wrong values

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've been playing with svg animation recently. More specifically I'm just trying to get the effect of lines drawing themselves. So far it makes sense, but I'm having some problems.

On complex shapes the values returned by `getTotalLength()` seem to be wrong. It usually says the path is longer than it is.

In this example, the path (on my screen) is around half of what's reported: 
https://jsfiddle.net/36u7Lztv/2/

HTML:

```
<svg  width="1023.5735" height="339.87985" viewBox="0 0 1023.5737 339.87985" >
    <g transform="translate(-2.8122176,-453.90997)" >
       <path id='lens_right' class='lens'
            d="m 316.71289,297.36523 c -0.11819,0.016 -0.24013,0.0412 -0.35742,0.0547 0.566,0.18666 1.12735,0.23429 1.68164,0.16602 -0.44147,-0.0734 -0.88314,-0.14373 -1.32422,-0.22072 z M 173.86328,445.8125 C 115.7806,445.9007 56.06865,450.63489 1.0585938,461.85352 l 1.9397734,72.7392 c -1e-7,0 16.2532068,18.31933 17.1835938,36.63281 7.809399,154.2024 84.019299,222.56445 230.091789,222.56445 117.58238,0 160.41001,-31.53414 192.45313,-124.72461 34.65112,-100.76402 54.39723,-115.49536 72.95078,-115.49536 18.55362,0 36.33586,14.73134 70.98281,115.49536 32.05142,93.19047 74.8706,124.72461 192.45703,124.72461 146.07668,0 222.2826,-68.36205 230.0918,-222.56445 0.9262,-18.31554 17.1719,-36.63477 17.1719,-36.63477 l 0,-73.26953 C 970.87866,455.60266 908.72901,458.90001 850.64648,458.8125 775.96903,458.69998 707.53291,462.34077 650.69355,469.17304 539.89171,481.65973 487.5315,480.99999 376.36719,464.59766 320.52651,453.26539 248.54104,445.69916 173.86328,445.8125 Z"
            transform="matrix(1.0086962,0,0,1,-8.9208996,-1.22e-4)"
            />
    </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: teal;
}

svg {
  width: 50%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #000000;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 1;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
  transition: all 3s linear;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var path1 = document.getElementById('lens_right');
var path1Len = path1.getTotalLength();

var strokeLen = path1Len; // easier troubleshooting

path1.style.strokeDasharray = strokeLen;
path1.style.strokeDashoffset = -strokeLen;

// add/remove border on hover
document.body.onmouseover = function() {
    path1.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
}

document.body.onmouseout = function() {
    path1.style.strokeDashoffset = -strokeLen;
}
```

You'll notice a bit of a delay before the border begins to draw.

Playing with the value of `strokeLen` (e.g. dividing `path1Len` by 2) can put the start of the line closer to the right spot, but hardcoding something like that probably isn't accurate on different devices and resolutions.

I'm getting the same results regardless of browser. I found some old Firefox bug reports from a few years ago involving this same issue, but they said it's fixed and mention that it wasn't an issue for Chrome.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is being caused by the fact that you are using:

```
vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
```

Using this means that you path is being transformed, but the stroke (and hence the dasharray) isn't.

If you remove the `vector-effect` and make the `stroke-width` bigger (so it is visible), you get a better result. Though you will still need to fix a couple of other things now.

https://jsfiddle.net/36u7Lztv/4/